# How to pass a data to a nested controller (UIContainerView)?

Tags: ios, swift, view, containers

I've searched everywhere for a solution but nothing. I have two view controllers and I want to pass data from viewController.swift to resultViewController.swift (the container view), i've succeeded to send data when I run it. but when i clicked increase button I can't send data again.

ViewController.swift:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var result: Int = 1

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
       // performSegueWithIdentifier("sendResult", sender: <#AnyObject?#>)
    }

    @IBAction func increas(sender: AnyObject) {
        result++
        performSegueWithIdentifier("sendResult", sender: self)

    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "sendResult"{
        var resultVC = segue.destinationViewController as! ResultViewController
        resultVC.result = self.result
        }
    }
}
```

ResultViewController.swift:

```
class ResultViewController: UIViewController {

    var result: Int!

    @IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        resultLabel.text = "\(result)"
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Send `result` to the `ResultViewController`? Are you trying to update it again in the `ViewController` and then pass the value in using the segue? What would you like to happen?

Comment: There is button I'v added with action called increase

Comment: It is in view controll and what it does increase result value and send it to container view ( ResultViewController. I don't know how to pass it.

Comment: Yes I can see that. But you said that you are sending it?

Comment: That's the point. I want to sent it via segue (emadded segue). I tried perform segue with identifier but didn't work

Comment: Why are you calling `performSegueWithIdentifer`? Have you set the segue using interface builder by dragging from the button to `ResultViewController`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Here's some working code.

First, remove your increase method and unhook it from your button in the Connections Inspector. Then delete your old segue in Interface Builder and create a new segue by dragging from the button to `ResultsViewController`. Make sure you give the segue a "sendResult" identifier in Interface Builder. In `ViewController`:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "sendResult" {
        result++
        var rvc = segue.destinationViewController as! ResultViewController
        rvc.result = result
    }
}
```

And then in `ResultsViewController`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!
var result : Int = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    resultLabel.text = "\(result)"

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Comment: When I delete the embedded segue, the resultViewController will not appear in containor view.

Comment: Are you re-adding it again?

Comment: Sure I'll take a look. That project does not contain `ResultViewController` or any modifications to the default storyboard. Is that the correct project?

Answer (score 0):

Nested ViewControllers are a bit tricky to use because from the parent controller point of view, all they see is a `UIView` (there is no `rootViewController` or `nestedViewController` property, which would be very nice to have).

The best way I have found to send/read data to/from the nested controller is by adding a reference to it on the parent controller.

It turns out that `prepareForSegue` is called after `viewDidLoad` for all nested view controllers. Then it is never called again, unless you call it manually. But you shouldn't and will not need to do that.

Here is how you can get a reference to the nested controller to use later in your code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var result: Int = 1
    private var resultVC: ResultViewController?  // Keep it optional

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func increas(sender: AnyObject) {
        result++
        // Update result value, keep optional reference for security
        // Here you could write & read values, call methods, etc.
        resultVC?.result = result
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "sendResult" {
          // Save reference to child view controller (use optional)
          resultVC = segue.destinationViewController as? ResultViewController
        }
    }
}
```

Once you have the reference to the nested view controller, you can use it anywhere in the code. To be safe, always use it with `?`.

Comment: this is my project to understand my situation https://github.com/d7oomalmalki/ContainerView i need to make increase button works.

Comment: The link does not seem tow work, I assume your project is private. Did you tried the code I shared? Did you get any errors?